localhost:8088 does not work on hadoop 3.3.6
localhost:8088 does not work on hadoop3.3.6 and localhost:9870 does not work
[[[[enter image description here]
(https://i.sstatic.net/OlBlZXs1.png)]
(https://i.sstatic.net/GPxD6mbQ.png)]
(https://i.sstatic.net/TGV1iwJj.png)]
(https://i.sstatic.net/jt9c9aJF.png)
localhost:8088 does not work on hadoop3.3.6 version and localhost:9870 does not work on same version
